# Dropping a table in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

Whenever I try to drop a table or create a table it is showing these errors:

```
DROP TABLE SUBURB;
DROP TABLE STOCKITEM;
DROP TABLE MANUFACTURER;
DROP TABLE WAREHOUSE;
DROP TABLE CITY;
DROP TABLE STATE;
```

> Error at line 1: ORA-02449: unique/primary keys in table referenced
>   by foreign keys

```
 CREATE TABLE STATE (
 statecode varchar(3)
 ,statename varchar(30)
 ,population number(8)
 ,primary key(statecode)
  );
```

> Error at line 1: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

Can anybody explain why this happens?

Comment: You have to drop in the correct order. If `TABLEA` has a foreign key relationship to `TABLEB`, you can't drop `TABLEB` because it violates the foreign key relationship in `TABLEA`. You have to drop `TABLEA` first, then you can drop `TABLEB`.

Comment: Try executing the drops one-by-one so you can see which one is causing the error to be raised.

Comment: You can also use DROP TABLE STATE CASCADE CONSTRAINTS; but please be aware that it will remove your foreign key constraints that link the table STATE.

Comment: I tired to drop all the table in the following order but it was not able to run

Comment: can't we do without cascade constraints @Vini.g.fer

Comment: No you can't if you want to drop a table with FK constraints you _have_ to drop the constraints as well. Where should they point to if the table is dropped?

Answer (score 15):

If you're really sure you want to drop the table even though it's referenced in foreign keys you can force it like this:

```
drop table state cascade constraints;
```

This syntax is defined in [the Oracle SQL Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9003.htm#SQLRF01806).

Note that this drops any foreign key relationships.  So you will need to recreate them after you have rebuilt the table (and its primary key).  Normally this is okay because the most common use case is trashing and re-creating schemas in Development or CI environments.

We can use `cascade constraints`  to make our build scripts easier to maintain. There are two alternatives:

1. Explicitly drop the foreign key constraints before dropping the
   tables, either with a script or with dynamic SQL.
2. Order the DROP
   TABLE statements so that dependent tables are zapped first, along
   with their pesky foreign keys.  Easy enough for a handful of tables,
   more painful with a large schema.

Answer (score 5):

You can use below query to fetch the references of table which should be dropped before dropping the table.

```
select table_name, constraint_name, status, owner
from dba_constraints
where 1=1
--and r_owner = :p_owner --if you know schema
and constraint_type = 'R'
and r_constraint_name in
(
   select constraint_name from dba_constraints
   where constraint_type in ('P','U')
   and lower(table_name) = lower(:p_table_name)
   --and r_owner = :p_owner
)
order by table_name, constraint_name
```

Answer (score 1):

if you create the primary key and also create the foreign key than you cannot drop the table
you drop the table in this way for example if you have the table of students or teachers you want to drop this table you should write

```sql
DROP TABLE students CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
```

and also you drop the table of teachers

```sql
DROP TABLE teachers CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
```

Answer (score 0):

***SUBURB***
Table is a parent table for any other table First you drop the child table then you can drop the `SUBURB` table....

And a table named as ***STATE*** is already present in your database...so you cant create the table having the same name....once if you drop the ***STATE*** table you can create another....

Answer (score 0):

here's the solution that works for me fine in Oracle sample database :

```
DROP TABLE ['Your_Table_Name'] STATE CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
```